# Move specific nodes to a node A and only the ones between the two occurrences of a t node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to fix a XML file (generated from a text file) with [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) or [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery), so I can do something useful with it. This is the input XML file:

```
<root>
    <main><id>100</id></main>
    <child>1</child>
    <child>2</child>
    <main><id>200</id></main>
    <child>1</child>
    <child>2</child>
    <child>3</child>
    <main><id>300</id></main>
    <child>1</child>
</root>
```

This is the output I like to have

```
<root>
    <main>
        <id>100</id>
        <children>
            <child>1</child>
            <child>2</child>
        </children>
    </main>
    <main>
        <id>200</id>
        <children>
            <child>1</child>
            <child>2</child>
            <child>3</child>
        </children>
    </main>
    <main>
        <id>300</id>
        <children>
            <child>1</child>
        </children>
    </main>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a simple rearrangement of the input XML based on intersection of two node-sets respect to the `main` context:

- **A** all preceding nodes of the next `main`, or all following nodes of the last `main` node

  ```
  "following-sibling::main[1]
     /preceding-sibling::node()
   | 
   following-sibling::*[count(current()/following::main[1])=0]"
  ```
- **B** all following nodes of the current `main` node

  ```
  "following-sibling::*"
  ```

In [XSLT 1.0] intersection is represented as:

```
    "$B[count(.|$A)=count($A)]"
```

In [XSLT 2.0] you use the `intersect` operator:

```
    "$A intersect $B"
```

The following transform is an example of XSLT 1.0 solution

**Note** This transform makes use the well known Identity transformation by including it from external file `identity.xsl`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="child"/>

    <xsl:template match="main">
        <xsl:variable name="A" 
            select="
            following-sibling::main[1]
                /preceding-sibling::node()
            |
            following-sibling::*
            [count(current()/following::main[1])=0]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="B" select="following-sibling::*"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|id"/>
            <children>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$B[count(.|$A) = count($A)]" 
                   mode="copy"/>
            </children>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, somehow I got an error: (Error) Expected Node-set in Path Expression. Did you test it then I will check my environment.

Comment: @Edwin yes I always test my answers. Tested with Saxon 6.5 (XSLT 1.0) and Saxon 9 (XSLT 2.0).

Comment: @Edwin now also successfully tested with MSXSL 4.5.

Comment: Thanks it works OK in altova xmlspy, I used jdeveloper. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with XSLT 1.0. I've commented as much as possible. I used a tree walking solution. Tree walking is not the easiest thing (for beginners) in XSLT. For a general explanation of this approach look here: [Dave Pawson XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html#d5509e1105)

Inside the `<root>` node the XSLT goes/walks step by step through the direct children of `<root>` and generates a new block of `<main>...</main>` (on every `<main>` node) or `<children>...</children>` (`<child>` which has a direct `<main>` parent) on some nodes.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- copy any attributes in root -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!-- walk through and copy nodes which are preceding main (if there are any?) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1][not(self::main)]" mode="walker"/>
    <!-- start walking mode with first main -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::main][1]" mode="walker"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- do not copy main, it will be copied later in walker mode -->
<xsl:template match="root/main"/>

<xsl:template match="main" mode="walker">
    <main>
      <!-- copy any attributes of main -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- copy all children of main -->
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <!-- begin walking and copying the next following-sibling node IF it is not main -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(self::main)]" mode="walker"/>
    </main>
    <!-- search the next main start and generate a new main block -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[self::main][1]" mode="walker"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- every child which has main as it first preceding-sibling generates a new children block -->
<xsl:template match="child[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::main]]" mode="walker">
    <children>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <!-- continue walking (through children) if the following-sibling node is NOT main -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(self::main)]" mode="walker"/>
    </children>
</xsl:template>

<!-- copy all other nodes in walking mode -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="walker">
    <!-- copy this node and children -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    <!-- walk to the next following-sibling IF it is not main -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(self::main)]" mode="walker"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Default: Copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <main>
    <id>100</id>
    <children>
      <child>1</child>
      <child>2</child>
    </children>
  </main>
  <main>
    <id>200</id>
    <children>
      <child>1</child>
      <child>2</child>
      <child>3</child>
    </children>
  </main>
  <main>
    <id>300</id>
    <children>
      <child>1</child>
    </children>
  </main>
</root>
```